# Cursor LOV Forms builder

Tags: cursor, oracleforms, lov

l have a problem with the cursor in Oracle Forms Builder 11. When user navigates from one field to another using TAB, l need that the cursor remain in the search field when the List of values opens. Can you help me

I tried changing the Filter before display to Yes, in the properties. The cursor is in the search field, but no record are visible.
P.S. sorry for my english[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACXxM.png)